# SSRS 2015 - hide a tablix column based on a value in the data set table and row group value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have one table used as a data set for 10 pages of a report.  I have created one tablix containing this data. This report is to be exported into excel with 10 different tabs.  I have grouped on the tableID and can produce a report that exports as excel with the 10 different tabs.  This is a row group and I do not have any column groups.

The table has 5 columns and I want to be able to set the column visibility based on the tableID grouping.  eg for tableID 1 i would like columns 1 and 2 to be hidden and tableID 2 I would like columns 5 to be hidden.  If I create separate tables and filter this works fine but not if it is just the one table and I group using tableID.

Answer (score 2):

**Step1:**

Create a list, group on tableID, and set the page break

**Step2:**

Create the table with your data (probably already done that)

**Step3:**

Select your table.
On your columns group activate advanced mode to show you the static columns.
Select each static column, and set the hidden expression

[image]

**Step4:**

Drag the table inside the list to embed it. Size the list to match your table size

[image]

**Executing the report:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this.  You have resolved my problem.  It works!